# Override authlogic's email validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

I am making a login using AuthLogic, but I would like 'email' to be optional. It seems however that authlogic out of the box makes this validated for. Anyone know a workaround?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

from the authlogic example rails application:

> 1. Set up your model
>
> Make sure you have a model that you
>   will be authenticating with. Since we
>   are using the User model it should
>   look something like:
>
> ```
> class User < ActiveRecord::Base
>   acts_as_authentic do |c|
>     c.my_config_option = my_value # for available options see documentation in: Authlogic::ActsAsAuthentic
>   end # block optional  
> end
> ```
>
> One thing to note here is that this tries
>   to take care of all the authentication
>   grunt work, including validating your
>   login, email, password, and token
>   fields. You can easily disable this
>   with configuration. Ex:
>   c.validate_email_field = false. See
>   the Authlogic::ActsAsAuthentic sub
>   modules in the documentation for more
>   details.

Key part to note:

> You can easily disable this with configuration. Ex:
>   c.validate_email_field = false.

Hope that helps.

Source: https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic_example

Comment: That is Austin! Thank you so much, friend

Answer (score 0):

While searching my contents ..i found out
http://rdoc.info/github/binarylogic/authlogic/master/Authlogic/ActsAsAuthentic/Email/Config#merge_validates_format_of_email_field_options-instance_method
this will surely help..